# Minusassign (-=) syntax error in ActionScript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax

Why can't I compile this little piece of code ?
I'm overriding x and y in my class so that's why I need `super.x`.

```
public class SimpleSprite extends Sprite
{
    override public function set x(value: Number): void
    {
        super.x -= 12;
        //super.x = super.x - 12;
    }
}

// or
public class SimpleSprite2 extends Sprite
{
    public function get xx(): Number
    {
        return super.x;
    }

    public function set xx(value: Number): void
    {
        super.x = value;
    }

    public function SimpleSprite2()
    {
        xx -= 12;
        super.x -= 12;
        // Error: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before minusassign.
    }
}
```

*I know I can write `super.x = super.x - 12;` but im lazy and i dont want 2 look 4 these inconsistencies when i get hit by syntax errors im also very much accustomed to those shortcuts with `-=`*

---

**Looks like my IDE (FlashDevelop 4.2.3) bears the blame for this.**

Comment: Are you overriding x in this class? If not, can't you use `x -= 12;` instead?

Comment: @3vilguy Yes. I added this info.

Comment: Wasn't before editing.
If just copy your class and I have no error. Sure you are not missing some semicolons in other part of this class?

Comment: @3vilguy Yes, I'm sure. I'm testing these examples. Looks like you can't minusassign properties from base classes.

Comment: Why not? I copy paste your class from here and I have no syntax error.

Comment: @3vilguy Don't tell me this error comes from the IDE (I use FlashDevelop 4.2.3). Which IDE do you use ?

Comment: Flash Builder 4.7 here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing syntactically wrong with what your doing. Your code works fine in my Flash Builder 4.7.

However, remember that `instance.x -= value;` is short for

```
instance.x = instance.x - value; 
//ie. 
instance.[set]x = instance.[get]x - value;
```

I mention this because of your top code:

```
override public function set x(value: Number): void
{
    super.x -= 12;
    //super.x = super.x - 12;
}
```

Makes me think you're trying to do something funny. Why are you decrementing in the set function?

If you need to have a seperate x value for a subclass, but can't change the interface (ie. you still want users to be able to say `mySubClassInstance.x = 123.0;`) do this:

```
public class DerivedSprite extends Sprite
{
    protected var derivedX:Number;
    public override function get x():Number
    {
        super.x = derivedX;
        return derivedX;
    }

    public override function set x(value:Number):void
    {
        super.x = value;
        derivedX = value;
    }

    public function DerivedSprite()
    {
        super();
        derivedX = super.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Why are you decrementing in the set function?"_ I filter the x and y properties of my sprites. So that they stay in specific boundaries. Like when you want to keep angle values between 0 and 360, you add or subtract 360.